# Are there any Apache Solr schema.xml generator tools?

Tags: xml, user-interface, solr, schema

I am just starting to work with Solr and I was surprised to not find any Solr admin interfaces, other than the admin gui that comes with solr, especially given Solr's popularity

I would love to see a gui tool for creating a schema.xml for example.

Can anyone suggest any such tools?

Thank you

Comment: I sincerely recommend to work with schema.xml by hand before looking after some gui tools. a) it is not that complicated b) schema.xml is the heart of everything. you should know in detail what is going on there.

Comment: I am planning to manually edit the schema.xml, i just wanted a better visual representation of what's going on and what my options are, so I can get a better undestanding of the subject

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the manage-schema file to `schema.xml`.

Sample file location: `C:\Bitnami\solr-5.5.0-1\apache-solr\solr\configsets\basic_configs\conf`

[image: See attached for the before and after renaming.]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how this answers the question

Comment: Your intention is to study and edit the schema.xml isn't? To better understand how it works, I encourage you to play around with it manually as it's not that hard to understand and to have a better first hand experience.